# Laravel 8 unique validation rule doesn't work with user_id

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using Laravel 8 and the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) validation rule to ensure that a record remains unique, I'm now trying to extend this so that it's unique per user as well, but when expanding the functionality and using the rule in array form it doesn't seem to validate the user ID and instead gives me a integrity constraint violation.

So I have a table called `brands`, and this table contains two columns in question: `brand` and `user_id`, I need to ensure that when storing a record that the brand is unique against the `brand` column and that the logged in in user's ID the one making the request, e.g:

Two users can have the same brand, but a single user can't have multiples of the same brand.

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'brand' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        Rule::unique('brands')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        })
    ],
    'url' => 'required|string',
    'telephone' => 'required|string|min:11|max:11'
]);
```

I've also tried:

```
'brand' => 'required|string|unique:brands,brand,user_id,' . Auth::id()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wong but I think it should be Auth::user->id(). Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) you have to use the `ignore()` function:

```
Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
```

on your case:

```
Rule::unique('brands')->ignore($user->id, 'user_id'),
```

Comment: Using this doesn't trigger `$validator->fails()` so the user ends up just seeing "Something went wrong" as a fallback, how can I get this to work with the validator fail so I can display an error

Comment: @RyanH What about form requests? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Surely `Rule::unique()` will return validation messages out of the box much like `unique:brands`, unless I'm mistaken?